# $location.path("/"); not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I am trying to use $location.path(), the url changes but whatever I have passed in .path is appened to my current url. I want that when I execute my addShow(), I want to go to index.html which is my home page. Could you please help.
The url changes like this:
http://localhost:8080/add
and when I execute my addShow function it changes to:
http://localhost:8080/add#/
I want it to change to go to my home page.

```
angular.module('app').controller("MainController",['$location', function($location) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.title = 'TV Show';
      vm.searchInput = '';
      vm.shows = [{
        title: 'Game of Thrones',
        year: 2011,
        favorite: true
      }, {
        title: 'Walking Dead',
        year: 2010,
        favorite: false
      }, {
        title: 'Firefly',
        year: 2002,
        favorite: true
      }, {
        title: 'Banshee',
        year: 2013,
        favorite: true
      }, {
        title: 'Greys Anatomy',
        year: 2005,
        favorite: false
      }];
      vm.orders = [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'Year Ascending',
        key: 'year',
        reverse: false
      }, {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Year Descending',
        key: 'year',
        reverse: true
      }, {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Title Ascending',
        key: 'title',
        reverse: false
      }, {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Title Descending',
        key: 'title',
        reverse: true
      }];
      vm.order = vm.orders[0];
      vm.new = {};
      vm.addShow = function() {
        vm.shows.push(vm.new);
        console.log(vm.shows);
        vm.new = {};
        $location.path("/");
      };

    }]);
```

my config function is as below:

```
    (function() {

  "use strict";

  angular
    .module("app")
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {


      //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'list.html',
          controller: 'MainController',
          controllerAs: 'main',
        })
        .when('/add', {
          templateUrl: 'add.html',
          controller: 'MainController',
          controllerAs: 'main',
        })
        ;

    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through your Plunkr (plnkr.co/edit/0z6ng0?p=preview), the issue is the way you are navigating to the Add page. This line - *a href="./add.html"* is redirecting the page directly to add.html. Instead use a function in the controller to change the location to *"/add"*.
**main.ctrl.js(Controller):** *(Add this function)*

```
vm.newShow = function() {
   $location.path('/add');
};
```

**List.html:**

```
<a href="">
      <button class="btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="main.newShow()">New Show</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replace `$location.path("/");` with
        `$window.location.href = "/";`

Comment: Hi... It didn't work. My project is on plunkr. The link is http://plnkr.co/edit/0z6ng0?p=preview

Can you please check here.

Comment: I get this error.

{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "child \"previewId\" fails because [previewId is required]",
  "validation": {
    "source": "params",
    "keys": [
      "previewId"
    ]
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

U need provide a [base url](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#relative-links) for your app, because when u call path method, angular treat 'http://localhost:8080/add' as the app base url,so works not correct.

Specify the url base in the head of your main html file.

```
<base href="/">
```

also if u want use html5 mode:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

[document guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

example: http://plnkr.co/edit/2EXVYKCjdKWPBd7LDEQB?p=preview

Comment: where do we need to add this base href. I tried adding in the home page and got the below error.

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

just use controllerAs: 'vm',i think it will work. just reply me